# Stream an audio file to Raspberry PI running Windows 10 IOT

Tags: javascript, c#, raspberry-pi2, windowsiot

I have a Raspberry PI 2 running Windows 10 IOT core and I want create a headless app to stream my video/audio to the device over network. The app should stream all audio/video files played on my computer to the Raspberry PI.